# Writing a batch file that runs robocopy from user input

Tags: batch-file, robocopy

How can I write a batch file that runs cmd.exe, enters the partial command `robocopy` then waits for user input to complete and execute the robocopy command? It seems like it should be the simplest thing to do but no method I've tried enters the command in such a way as to hold and wait for user input and then successfully execute the completed robocopy command

For example:

```bat
@echo off
set var="robocopy "
cmd.exe %var%
```

appears to work but then, for example, user-inputting /? to bring up robocopy's info instead brings up `cmd.exe`'s info

Another example:

```bat
@echo off
cmd /k robocopy
```

Runs `robocopy` with no destination/source folders or switches, then closes `robocopy` and waits for a new user-inputted command.

what I'm trying to do is have a batch file that when I click it a cmd window will open with the partial command `robocopy` already entered ready for me to complete the command with source/destination/switches and execute it with an enter key press - I use `robocopy` all day long so this would be a big time saver.

Comment: Not with batch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's not possible in the way you seem to think. That would mean to mess with the keyboard buffer (was pretty common with the C64 back in those times, but it's not possible in (pure) batch).

But the following should give you a good start for automation. It assumes, you use the same parameters each time and just want to give it a source and a destination folder. Adjust to your needs (especially the params - I added `/L` to prevent it from unwanted actions while testing):

```
@echo off
set "command=robocopy"
set "params=/L /E /MOV /MT:12 /FP /log+:robocopy.log /TEE"
set /p "source=Enter Source: "
set /p "destin=Enter Destination: "
%command% "%source%" "%destin%" %params%
```

The `cmd.exe` or `cmd.exe /k` isn't necessary, until you want robocopy to work in a new window.